# UWP MediaPlayer still playing music in redirected app instance

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, media-player

I wanted to make it so that when opening a media file (music or video), it opens in one application window, and not create another window with another file being played (for example, so that two tracks do not play at the same time or two videos do not play at the same time). I made a redirect in the Main method, and it works almost correctly, when opening another media file, the application opens it in an already existing window, as if overwriting the previous instance of the application.
But the main problem is that the music in the player from the previous instance continues to play and overlaps with the sound from the new instance.

**Main method with redirection:**
`static void Main()
{
IActivatedEventArgs activatedArgs = AppInstance.GetActivatedEventArgs();

```
    if (activatedArgs is FileActivatedEventArgs fileArgs)
    {
        IStorageItem file = fileArgs.Files.FirstOrDefault();
        if (file != null)
        {
            AppInstance instance;

            if (Constants.SupportedImagesFormates.Any(x => file.Name.Contains(x)))
            {
                instance = AppInstance.FindOrRegisterInstanceForKey(file.Name);
            }
            else
            {
                instance = AppInstance.FindOrRegisterInstanceForKey("playbackMedia");
            }

            if (instance.IsCurrentInstance)
            {
                Application.Start((p) => new App());
            }
            else
            {
                instance.RedirectActivationTo();
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Application.Start((p) => new App());
    }
}`
```

Any ideas how to fix it? I hope I explained it clearly...

Comment: UWP doesn't seem to have `static void Main()`, did you refer to any tutorial? and how is `Constants.SupportedImagesFormates` implemented?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/multi-instance-uwp refer to this. Constants.SupportedImagesFormates is just an array with supported file formates strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When opening a new instance, you need to pause the MediaPlayer manually.

It is recommended to use [MediaPlayer.Pause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.playback.mediaplayer.pause?view=winrt-22621#windows-media-playback-mediaplayer-pause) to pause your audio or video files when opening new instance.